# Matrix multiplication of three very small matrices in AVX2, of runtime-variable size

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, avx2

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate the following matrix product using AVX2 and FMA3:

```
C=B' * A * B
```

The matrices are quite small with just a few entries. Matrix `A` is square whereas matrix `B` is rectangular.

I am looking for a solution in C++.

So far I have tried to call two times a matrix-matrix product function and store the transposed matrix `B` in some temporary space, but everything so far was slower compared to the non vectorized and serial code.

For matrix-matrix product I use the following code:

```
void matrix_matrix(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int result[N][N])
    {
__m256i vec_multi_res = _mm256_setzero_si256(); //Initialize vector to zero
__m256i vec_mat1 = _mm256_setzero_si256(); //Initialize vector to zero
__m256i vec_mat2 = _mm256_setzero_si256(); //Initialize vector to zero
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        //Stores one element in mat1 and use it in all computations needed before proceeding
        //Stores as vector to increase computations per cycle
        vec_mat1 = _mm256_set1_epi32(mat1[i][j]);

        for (k = 0; k < N; k += 8)
        {
            vec_mat2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&mat2[j][k]); //Stores row of second matrix (eight in each iteration)
            vec_multi_res = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&result[i][k]); //Loads the result matrix row as a vector
            vec_multi_res = _mm256_add_epi32(vec_multi_res ,_mm256_mullo_epi32(vec_mat1, vec_mat2));//Multiplies the vectors and adds to th the result vector

            _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&result[i][k], vec_multi_res); //Stores the result vector into the result array
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The code is according to this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177616/avx-simd-in-matrix-multiplication).

Comment: A standard matrix product combines rows to columns, which is a very defavorable layout for the SIMD instructions. A modified multiplication that would combine rows to rows could be implemented much more efficiently. Your case is a nice opportunity to use this trick, as you need to handle both `B` and `B'`.

Comment: How big is "quite small"? Do you know the dimensions at compile time? Is `A` symmetric?

Comment: The dimensions are not known during compile time. A can be symmetric but this is not a must have. "Quite small" is something around 6x6 or 8x8 for A and something around 6x24 or similar for B.

Comment: If you have "quite small" matrices with sizes not guaranteed to be multiples of 4 or 8, optimization might be hard. You have to compromise at some point between efficiency and code/binary size. Maybe padding your matrix-sizes to multiples of 8 is an option? Also, for sufficiently big matrices exploiting the symmetry of `A` (and thus `C`) is likely worth having an extra implementation. But currently your question is too vague, IMO.